# Avro 1.9.0 failed to compile generated java code with error message: cannot find symbol method customEncode(org.apache.avro.io.Encoder)

Tags: java, avro

I have two schemas:

```
DataRecord.avsc:
{
    "namespace": "com.mycompany",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "DataRecord",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "id", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},   
        {"name": "type", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},       
        {"name": "content", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
        {"name": "error", "type": ["null", "com.mycompany.Error"], "default": null} 
    ]
}
```

```
Error.avsc:
{
    "namespace": "com.mycompany",
    "type": "error",
    "name": "Error",
    "fields": [
    ]
}
```

It was working with Avro 1.8.2, but after I upgraded to Avro 1.9.0, and then I tried to build, it failed to compile and generated the following error logs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) on project avro-error-type-missing-custom-coding: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /workspaces/myspace/avro-error-type-missing-custom-coding/target/generated-sources/avro/com/mycompany/DataRecord.java:[570,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method customEncode(org.apache.avro.io.Encoder)
[ERROR] location: variable error of type com.mycompany.Error
[ERROR] /workspaces/myspace/avro-error-type-missing-custom-coding/target/generated-sources/avro/com/mycompany/DataRecord.java:[608,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method customDecode(org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder)
```

It seems that SpecificRecordBase has methods of `customEncode()` and `customDecode()` in Avro 1.9.0, but SpecificExceptionBase doesn't.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I've opened a bug with AVRO because I'm hitting this too - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2771

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the Avro depenency in you pom.xml.
Source: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/getting-started-java/

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```